# Is it bad practice to save multiple files in Android?

Tags: android, file

Instead of having one large file, to have multiple files, one for each specific thing you do inside the app?

Comment: What would these files contain?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Explain what you want to do and provide some code examples.

Comment: well, currently it saves a list of names to a file called myapp_names, but I would like to start saving lists compiled from those names. So my question was would it be considered bad practice to save those lists to a different file called something like myapp_lists?

Comment: it would be a better practice to use the SQLite database provided and create tables instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why SQLite has been invented, complexity is easier to manage in a database

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with it. Unless you're creating thousands of files, there's no harm splitting it up.